# When dealing with hexadecimal numbers how do I use bit offset and length to get a value?

Tags: hex

I have the following number

0000C1FF61A40000

The offset or start is 36 or 0x23

The length of the number is 12 or 0xc

Can someone help me understand how to get the resulting value? I thought the offset meant what pair of hex numbers to start with and then length would be how many to grab. There definitely aren't 36 pairs, only 8. Not sure how I'd do a length of 12 with only 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each hex digit represents four binary bits.  Therefore your offset of 36 bits (which BTW is 0x24, not 0x23) is equivalent to 9 hex digits.  So discard the rightmost 9 digits from your original number, leaving you with `0000C1F`.

Then the length of the number you want is 12 bits, which is 3 hex digits.  So discard all but the rightmost 3 digits, leaving you with `C1F` as the answer.

If the numbers of bits had not been nice multiples of 4 then you would have had to convert the original hex number into binary, then discard `offset` number of bits from the right, retain only the rightmost `length` bits from the result, and finally convert those `length` bits back into hex.

Comment: This looks right to me but then I'm looking at other explanations on this sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oumkq83oMC7sUsSIggGv-BK4hmQbXqV5Lp1j2pPncLE/edit#gid=934656030 second sheet and some offsets are 1 and 7. Ugh, if nothing else I'll accept this because I'm wondering if they are wrong. If you notice on the 5th sheet whoever wrote that had the 1 off from the other values hex value for their offsets.

Comment: Oh and thanks a bunch. This was seriously vexing me.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on in that spreadsheet.  It would help if it noted what the actual values were that had been extracted from the messages.  It's possible that he's counting offsets from the left instead of the right, and it's possible that he's starting his counting from 1 instead of the more conventional 0.  BTW, "Offset" in in the fifth sheet ("Notes from reeeee") seems to be used in the sense of "bias", an adjustment to the arithmetic value of the extracted bits to give the actual value (e.g. a lat bitfield value of 0 means -89, a long bitfield value of 0 means -179).

Comment: Ah, https://hackaday.com/2013/10/22/can-hacking-the-in-vehicle-network/ shows a byte/bit numbering chart for a CAN message.  Bytes are numbered from 0 as the first byte, bits are numbered starting from 0 on the right (LSB) within the first byte, and then the numbering continues from the LSB of subsequent bytes.  So bit 8 is the rightmost bit of byte 1 (the second byte), and so on.  The location of a multi-bit field is specified by its rightmost bit (which is not necessarily the highest- or lowest-numbered bit in the field) and extends leftwards from there for the required number of bits.

Comment: Even with the 5th spreadsheet I've though that any arithmetic was done after the fact. I thought that all of this could be simplified thinking of it more as a string, you have 16 individual chars. Start 9th from the right take 3 more and now convert that data and then do your calculations. Not entirely sure if that's what to do though.

Comment: I'll have to look up what LSB is, but what I'm hearing in my head is each part of the message is 1 byte with consists of 2 bits...ugh lol. I'm actually writing a program to calculate and verify the messages coming out because that's easier for me lol.

Comment: That site talks about DBC's which someone else started https://www.focusrs.org/attachments/rs_hs-txt.331654/ but I'm not even sure how this stuff helps you because it doesn't describe how to determine a value. At least that I can see.

Comment: Sorry, LSB is "Least Significant Bit", the bit that represents the "2^0" or "1" value in a binary number.  The fields don't correspond to characters in the hex representation of the message, because the field lengths aren't necessarily aligned on four-bit boundaries and the field lengths aren't necessarily multiples of four bits.  So you can't treat the message as a string. You need to convert the message from hex to binary, and then extract the bits that make up each field.  Then you can interpret each field as a separate binary number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200542/discussion-between-rball-and-ottomeister).